# Accessing the current activity when running an NunitLite test

Tags: xamarin.android

I've got an ISettings interface which is implemented in a platform-specific manner on Mono For Android and iOS. For Mono For Android, I'm using Activity.GetSharedPreferences to implement my settings - and this works fine from my application.

However, I want to be able to test this with NunitLite (which I'm using successfully to test my other core code).

The problem is that for my test fixture, I need an Activity on which to call GetSharedPreferences. Is there a way of accessing the currently running Activity either generically or via the NunitLite implementation?

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Shared preferences via:

```
Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("whatever", FileCreationMode.Private)
```

You don't need an activity.

Comment: Aha - thanks a lot. That's a lot easier than passing the activity.